# How to display images only after html is properly rendered?

Tags: javascript, html

I am fetching all my friend's profile images and making a widget which will  display images one by one on next button clicks. When I make a request to facebook server, in response while html is rendering I can see all images getting displayed on browser and once loading is done everything fits perfectly in widget. How can I avoid these image pictures getting displayed while my page is still loading.

I have heard something about lazyloading which will load images only when page is scolled down. I don't have any scroll down option nor have any idea how to use ladyload but is there anything similar which would be helpful to me?

Comment: You have to use javascript in this case.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa please provide any link or explanation how javascript will be used here if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You could use css to hide all the images in the widget:

```
#widget img {display:none;}
```

Then use jquery to show them when the DOM is read yand all images have been loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#widget img').show()
});
```

Something like this would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to develop only to supported browsers [check it here] https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr

you better use built-in image lazy loading like this:

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/300.jpg" loading="lazy" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There's various options for lazy loading images, so long as you use JavaScript.

There's quite a few libraries to help you, such as jquery's lazy load plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Or various alternatives you'll find via our old friend Google :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery Lazy Load library. Here is a nice introduction: http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/lazy-loading-images-with-jquery/22

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).
jQuery is "A fast, concise, library that simplifies how to traverse HTML documents, handle events, perform animations, and add AJAX."

Jquery scripts are usually started with this commands

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });
```

so the commands will only be executed after the page is completely rendered.

Here you can find some [jQuery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)